# How to setup DHCP on network

Tags: networking, dhcp, pfsense

I'm trying to setup a home network that uses a pfSense VM as its main router and then I have multiple Ubiquiti AC access points for wireless. I also have another Windows VM that is running DHCP and NPS for the network. How can I get the Ubiquiti access points to forward DHCP to the Windows VM? I've tried enabling DHCP relay in the pfSense router however that had no effect. Is there a setting I'm missing here? The access points are plugged into a 'web smart switch' but I can't find any setting in the switch for DHCP either. I’m also planning on setting up a wired network, is there any way to forward the router and DHCP server info to wired clients on the switch? If you need any more info please ask or PM me.

Thanks, Gabriel

Comment: How are your APs configured? It sounds like they're not putting wireless clients on the same LAN as your DHCP server.

Comment: The APs are configured to put wireless clients on the same LAN I believe. The DHCP server has an IP of 10.72.1.3. The Access Points are 10.72.2.2 and 10.72.2.3. All with a subnet mask of /16. If I assign a static IP to wireless clients I get connectivity.  Also, I looked into the DHCP logs on pfSense and after every connection attempt this appears in the log:
dhcrelay  3 bad udp checksums in 5 packets